# Given the $P⇒Q$ and $¬P$, prove that we cannot deduce $¬Q.$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

> Given the known theorems $P \Rightarrow Q$ and $\lnot P$, prove that we cannot deduce $\lnot Q.$

I made the truth table for $P \Rightarrow Q:$

[image: if p then q]

Now, if $P \Rightarrow Q$ is a theorem, that means that we must exclude the second row of the truth table.

If $\lnot P$ is also a theorem, that means that $\lnot P$ is true, so $P$ must be false. Therefore, we must look in the last 2 rows of the truth table, since they're the only ones where $\lnot P$ and $P \Rightarrow Q$ are true at the same time.

I don't understand why we can't deduce $\lnot Q$ from $P \Rightarrow Q$ and $\lnot P.$ After all, if we are looking in the fourth row of the truth table where $P \Rightarrow Q$ is true and  $\lnot P$ is true, then$\lnot Q$ is also true.

Comment: Doesn't your third row provide the counter-example?

Comment: +1 to your question.  Nicely presented and reasoned, with good work shown.  As you reasoned, the combined premises of [1] $P \implies Q$ and [2] $\neg P$ indicate that only rows three and four are pertinent.  For the assertion to hold, the conclusion that $Q$ is always false would have to hold for both of the pertinent rows.  As the comment of John Douma indicates, row three is therefore a counter-example to the assertion.

Comment: If Spot is a dog, then Spot is a mammal. Spot is not a dog.

Comment: 1. What if  $P$ is $Q\land \neg Q?$ Then $\neg P$ is $(\neg Q)\lor Q$..... or 2. If I am asleep then I am not-invisible. Does it follow that if I am awake then I am invisible? .... or 3 . $P\implies Q$ is $\mathbf {defined} $ as $(\neg P)\lor Q.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> > Given the known theorems $P \Rightarrow Q$ and $\lnot P$, prove that we cannot deduce $\lnot Q.$
>
> I don't understand why we can't deduce $\lnot Q$ from $P \Rightarrow Q$ and $\lnot P.$
>
> After all, if we are looking in the fourth row of the truth table where $P \Rightarrow Q$ is true and  $\lnot P$ is true, then$\lnot Q$ is also true.

1. As you have explained, the truth table shows that when $(P⇒Q)$ and
   $(¬P)$ are both true, there are two possibilities: $(¬Q)$ is either true (row 4) or false (row 3).

   So, $(P⇒Q)$ and $(¬P)$ both being true does ***not*** necessitate/imply that $(¬Q)$ is also true.

   In other words, the result $(¬Q)$ cannot be ***deduced*** from the
   theorems $(P⇒Q)$ and $(¬P).$
2. Concretely: given that (if today is Friday, then today is a weekday)
   and that (today is not Friday), it is invalid to deduce that (today is a
   weekend).
3. The point is that there are infinitely many ways to give meanings to
   $P$ and $Q$ (like how I have just done), and whether row 3 or 4
   applies depends on the assigned meanings. That is, the infinitely many interpretations of $P$ and $Q$ fall into two disjoint sets: those that correspond to row 3 and those that correspond to row 4.

   To **deduce a conclusion** using a truth table requires that within the
   rows where the premises are all true, the conclusion is *invariably* true.